# AWS Security group cleanup

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have fairly large EC2 estate and found ourselves in a situation with hundreds of Security Groups.  Has anyone found a way to do he following:

- List security groups not associated with instances
- Export each security group with associated instances and rules

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a security group that's associated with a network interface, ie a instance that is either running or stopped. However, if you create instances from an AMI, and there are no instances or other resources like load balancers currently referencing a security group, they could be deleted.

Easiest thing to do is try to delete all security groups, no group associated with a instance that is running or stopped will be deleted.

If you have custom requirements you can write a lambda to accomplish what you need to, based on any logic you would care to write.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, unfortunately won't work for us as we have a fleet of instances that start up and shutdown on schedule around the clock depending on users hours and location.

Comment: I just tried it, security groups associated with stopped instances are not deleted. However, if you create instances from an AMI, and there are no instances currently referencing a security group, they could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Play a bit around with [aws command-line interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or with python's library [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html).

For the aws CLI you have a command to dump in json all the existing security groups with rules called [describe-security-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html)

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups --output json
# sample output
{
    "SecurityGroups": [
        {
            "IpPermissionsEgress": [], 
            "Description": "group desc", 
            "IpPermissions": [
                {
                    "PrefixListIds": [], 
                    "FromPort": 27004, 
                    "IpRanges": [], 
                    "ToPort": 27049, 
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp", 
                    "UserIdGroupPairs": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "name", 
                            "UserId": "0511234123441", 
                            "GroupId": "sg-b0674836"
                        }
```

For the second part, you have [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) subcommand witch will dump a description of all your instances that will include the associated security groups. You will have to write a small program to process those json outputs but all the data you need to cross-reference instances and groups rules are there. You can even use [jmespath](http://jmespath.org/) queries to clean the json output from undesired data.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,SecurityGroups]" --output json

[
    [
        "i-0c7bbc88743583793", 
        [
            {
                "GroupName": "group1", 
                "GroupId": "sg-a3f77f1d4"
            }
        ]
    ], 
    [
        "i-0f4ab88f9f9853a", 
        [
            {
                "GroupName": "group2", 
                "GroupId": "sg-7e99434"
            }
        ]
    ], 

....
```

If you opt for boto3 library you'll find that the inputs and outputs of the library are very similar, having both, [describe instances function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=describe%20instances#EC2.Client.describe_instances) and [describe security group function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_groups.)

Also take care because the code can change a bit if you are using EC2 Classic security group or VPC security groups, as they are a bit different.